# jQuery highlight.js modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I have found a great jQuery highlight plugin, but I need some modification.
My HTML looks like:

Here is some text

Here is some different text

etc.
lots of lines

I'd like to modify [this](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/833/on-page-text-highlighting-Search-with-jQuery) plugin like if someone search for a word on the page hide all paragraph in the content div just show those what is containing the highlighted text.
Or when someone searching give a class tot he other divs like "hidden" or something.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...
I modified the javascript like this:

```
$(function() {
jQuery('#text-search').bind('keyup change', function(ev) {
    // pull in the new value
    var searchTerm = jQuery(this).val();

    // remove any old highlighted terms
    jQuery('.toggle').removeHighlight();

    // line to remove the hidden class
    jQuery( ".toggle p" ).removeClass( "hidden" )

    // disable highlighting if empty
    if ( searchTerm ) {
        // highlight the new term
        jQuery('.toggle').highlight( searchTerm );

        //line to add the hidden class
        jQuery('.toggle p:not(:contains('+ searchTerm +'))').closest('p').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```